# No accounts found in useMsal hook when using loginRedirect

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, msal-react

I'm trying to use MSAL to authenticate users. If I authenticate using `instance.loginRedirect()`the value of `accounts` from calling `useMsal()` is always an empty array, but is correctly populated if I use `instance.loginPopup()`.

My Login component is as follows:

```js
export default function Login() {
  const { instance } = useMsal();

  const signInRedirect = (instance: IPublicClientApplication) => {
    instance.loginRedirect();
  };

  const signInPopup = (instance: IPublicClientApplication) => {
    instance.loginPopup(loginRequest);
  };
  return (
    <ScreenContainer pageTitle={"Login"}>
      <div className="login-wrapper">
        <h1>App</h1>
        <Button onClick={() => signInRedirect(instance)}>Login Redirect</Button>
        <Button onClick={() => signInPopup(instance)}>Login Popup</Button>
      </div>
    </ScreenContainer>
  );
}
```

The `AuthValidator` component validates the auth status and is as follows:

```js
    export default function AuthValidator() {
      const { accounts, inProgress, instance } = useMsal();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log("accounts", accounts); //This is always just an empty array.
    
        if (inProgress === "none" && accounts.length > 0) {
          //process logged in user..
        }
      }, [accounts, instance, inProgress]);
    
      return null;
    }
```

My app structure is as follows:

```js
    root.render(
      <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate
            loading={
              <LoaderWrapper>
                <h1>Loading...</h1>
              </LoaderWrapper>
            }
            persistor={persistor}
          >
            <AuthValidator /> 
            <BrowserRouter>
              <Routes />
            </BrowserRouter>
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </MsalProvider>
    );
```

My msal_config file is as follows:

```js
export const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "XXX",
    authority: `XXX`,
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/auth-redirect",
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
  },
};

export const loginRequest = {
  scopes: ["User.Read"],
  forceRefresh: false, // Set this to "true" to skip a cached token and go to the server to get a new token
};

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
export default msalInstance;
```

Here's the pertinent section from my package.json:

```json
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.37.1",
    "@azure/msal-react": "^1.5.8",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
```

I will be very, very grateful for any help as I have spent the last couple of hours trying to figure out where I'm going wrong. Thank you!